# CallKit View running in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, callkit

I am Using `CallKit` in my app. There I face some problem.

1. When there is an incoming call I receive like below UI.

[image]

But I should have receive UI like

[image]

after receiving call it will goto above image. But why I am getting like that I can't find out.

2. After receiving call from no-1 image it take me to my app and in my app after end the call this no-1 image view UI still run in background. how can I stop this.
3. Can I customize no-1 image view that is can I reduce button?

Comment: I think It's default functionality of callkit. when your phone is not locked then you receive first UI but when your phone is locked then UI is changed to 2nd one.

Comment: But I am getting 1st UI when my device is locked.any help

Comment: Please check this tutorial of callkit https://www.raywenderlich.com/150015/callkit-tutorial-ios